# django form: pass parameter to is_valid

Tags: django, forms, validation, parameter-passing, abstract

I have an `abstract form` and 2 forms using it. In the `is_valid` method of the abstract form, I check for a condition and that condition depends on the form calling the method. 
The line is:

```
if eval(self.cleaned_data.get("validated_modif")):
```

According to the form, it should be replaced by one of the following lines:

```
if act.validated_attendance==0: #MinAttend form
if act.validated<2: #Act form
```

I have a code that works. But it is **very (very) dirty, I am looking for a better idea.**

**forms.py:**

```
class AbstractModif(forms.Form):
    releve_mois_modif=forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=12)

    class Meta:
        #abstract form
        abstract = True

    #check if the searched act already exists in the db and has been validated
    def is_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # run the parent validation first
        valid=super(AbstractModif, self).is_valid()

        # we're done now if not valid
        if not valid:
            return valid

        #if the form is valid
        Model=Act
        fields={}
        fields["releve_mois"]=self.cleaned_data.get("releve_mois_modif")

        try:
            act=Model.objects.get(**fields)
            if Model!=Act:
                act=act.act
            #MinAttend form: check act.validated_attendance=0
            #Act form: check act.validated<2
            if eval(self.cleaned_data.get("validated_modif")):
                self._errors['__all__']=ErrorList([u"The act you are looking for has not been validated yet!"])
                return False
        except Exception, e:
            self._errors['__all__']=ErrorList([u"The act you are looking for doesn't exist in our database!"])
            print "exception", e
            return False

        # form valid -> return True
        return True
```

**form_1.py:**

```
class Modif(AbstractModif):
    #fake field for the is_valid method
    validated_modif=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="act.validated<2")
```

**form_2.py**

```
class Modif(AbstractModif):
    #fake field for the is_valid method
    validated_modif=forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="act.validated_attendance==0")
```

**form.html**

```
<!-- hidden field for the is_valid method of the form -->
{{ modif.validated_modif }}
```

I use `eval` and the initial value of a `hidden field` to check the condition. Do you have a nicer solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an immensely bad idea. You're running eval on input received from the browser. So if I use the browser dev tools to modify the contents of the hidden field to `os.system('rm -rf /')`, what do you think would happen?

I can't see any need for this at all. You have two form subclasses; why don't you simply put the validation in a method in those subclasses?

```
class Form1(AbstractForm):
    def validate_modif(self, act):
        return act.validated < 2

class Form(AbstractForm):
    def validate_modif(self, act):
        return act.validated_attendance == 0
```

and you can simply call `self.validate_modif(act)` to perform the validation.

Note also that you should *not* be overriding `is_valid()`, but `clean()`. And your Meta class does nothing because this is a normal Form, not a ModelForm.

Comment: Thanks it works. I know it was a bad idea but I never thought I could call a child method from the abstract form. Why should I use `clean` and not `is_valid`?